# What is standard web.xml java header to get <jsp-config> tag working?

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish, glassfish-3, web.xml

I've got a GlassFish 3.1.2 app server and I've started using JSP pages so I'm interested in configuring the encoding correctly for UTF-8.

My original working `web.xml` file started with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" 
   "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
```

but then I added the following to it to force UTF-8 encoding

```
<jsp-config>
   <jsp-property-group>
       <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
       <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
   </jsp-property-group> 
</jsp-config>
```

and my GlassFish 3.1.2 server log file reported

```
Element type <jsp-config> must be declared web.xml
```

In an attempt to fix the error, I changed the start of my `web.xml` file to be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
 version="2.4" >
```

and now I'm getting a GlassFish server error

```
Invalid Deployment Descriptors in Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml ...
One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":servlet-class, 
         "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":jsp-file}' is expected.
```

Is my syntax off? How to get `<jsp-config>` working with header in `xml.web` file for version 2.3?

UPDATE 1

If I start the `web.xml` file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_3.xsd"
    version="2.3">

<display-name>myApp</display-name>
<description>My Application</description>

<listener>
    <listener-class>...</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>MessageBrokerServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>...</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>...</param-name>
        <param-value>...</param-value>
   </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Reg</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.mydomain.servlet.Reg</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Reg</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/reg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>

</web-app>
```

I see this error:

> ```
> [#|2014-11-06T13:03:59.779-0800|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8015:
> ```
>
> Invalid Deployment Descriptors in Deployment descriptor file
>   WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [myapp].  Line 7 Column 41 --
>   s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema
>   elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'var _U =
>   "undefined";    var g_HttpRelativeWebRoot = "/ocom/";'.|#]
>
> [#|2014-11-06T13:03:59.779-0800|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8005:
>   Deployment Descriptor parsing failure : s4s-elt-character:
>   Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other
>   than 'xs:appinfo'  and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'var _U = "undefined"; 
>   var g_HttpRelativeWebRoot = "/ocom/";'.|#]

UPDATE 2

Alternatively, I also have a `glassfish-web.xml` file in `WEB-INF` directory. If I revert the `web.xml` file back to original and place the `<jsp-config>` section in `glassfish-web.xml` instead of `web.xml`, the server starts fine. Which file is `<jsp-config>` supposed to go in, or does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To configure JSP with UTF-8 you need to use, at the first line of the jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

You should use this but with your version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

An example of my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>base</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/spring-mvc-dispatcher.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring-database.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: thanks @stel, where can i find the right syntax to use with version 2.3?

Comment: @user46688 change the _3_0.xsd and version="3.0" to _2_3.xsd and version="2.3"

Comment: thanks @stel, with those changes I get this error: `Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinf
o' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'var _U = "undefined";`

Comment: can you edit your question and put the full web.xml and the full stacktrace? Those only say you have a whitespace that is not allow.

Comment: I think what I dont understand you. Sorry. To configure correctly a jsp with UTF-8 you need to add this to the first line of the jsp


<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Rollback the change and delete the <jsp-config> tag.

Sorry again if I have you confused.

Comment: I was trying to make the change globally (as shown here: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletRequest). Thanks anyway

Comment: I tried to regroup and ask a cleaner question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791888/jsp-cant-figure-out-how-to-set-utf-8-for-glassfish-3-1-2-response

Answer (score 0):

For servlet 3.1 api level use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1"
  metadata-complete="true">
```